# folder inside the project can't access other developers after pull the project

Tags: git, file, heroku, gitlab

I have project In Git Lab. Its files structure like that

```
>Root 
    >Adminpanel
    >Userclient
    >Backend
```

I run `git init` inside Backend folder for host my Backend in Heroku

After deploying Backend in Heroku I `push` code to Git Lab

Then after other developers `pull` the project. they can’t access to Backend folder.

How can I resolve that problem?

Comment: You have turned Backend into a submodule. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=heroku+submodule

Comment: i think my problem is my project have two git init inside a project

Comment: That’s what I just said.